# How to make specific part of a tree node text colored in c# winform application

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview, overriding

I am working on an application in which there is a tree view.And recently, I implemented search functionality on it.All it does is search the child nodes of the selected node for the entered keyword and displays only those nodes which have that keyword in their text or tag information in tree view structure. Now, I want to highlight the text of these searched nodes which matches the keyword.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself, it is done by using the draw node event handler and drawing custom made triangle inside the node.

Answer (score 0):

you can set `BackColor` to highlight background of a node

```
treeNode.BackColor = Color.Cyan;
```

you can set `ForeColor` to highlight text of a node

```
treeNode.ForeColor = Color.Green;
```

more advanced approach is to draw nodes in `treeView.DrawNode` event handler

Comment: But I want only specific part of the text to be highlighted not the whole text.